# Using Flags to control Java threads is not working

Tags: java

I want to use flag to control threads and exit accordingly. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class ThreadFlagExample {

    private static final AtomicBoolean running0 = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final AtomicBoolean running1 = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        running0.set(true);
        running1.set(true);

        Runnable task = () -> {
            try {
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("name = " +name + ", running0 = " +running0.get() + ", running1 = " +running1.get());
                if (name == "Thread-0" && running0.get()) {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("Foo Thread-0");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("Bar Thread-0");
                    }
                }
                if (name == "Thread-1" && running1.get()) {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("Foo Thread-1");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("Bar Thread-1");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " interrpted");
            }
        };

        // run in a separate thread
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(task);
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(task);
        thread2.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        running0.set(false);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        running1.set(false);
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it display the following output:

```
bash-4.4$ java ThreadFlagExample
name = Thread-0, running0 = true, running1 = true
name = Thread-1, running0 = true, running1 = true
^C
```

I expect the program to run Thread-0 and display the messages for 5 and and Thread-1 for 10 seconds. However, the code inside the two if block seem never get executed, and the program just hang there.
Could anyone point out what is not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do.  You want to start two threads, then have one thread stop after 5 seconds and the other one stop after 10.  Once they're both stopped, the program exits.

You have two problems.  First of all, you're comparing strings with `==`, which checks for the two strings to be literally the same object rather than to have the same value.  This will always be `false` in your case, which explains why your code isn't doing anything.

The other problem is that you're never checking the values of your flags once you start looping in each thread, so your attempts to stop them won't work.  Here's your code with those two issues fixed, which seems to work:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Test {

    private static final AtomicBoolean running0 = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final AtomicBoolean running1 = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        running0.set(true);
        running1.set(true);

        Runnable task = () -> {
            try {
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("name = " +name + ", running0 = " +running0.get() + ", running1 = " +running1.get());
                if (name.equals("Thread-0")) {
                    while (running0.get()) {
                        System.out.println("Foo Thread-0");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("Bar Thread-0");
                    }
                }
                if (name.equals("Thread-1")) {
                    while (running1.get()) {
                        System.out.println("Foo Thread-1");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("Bar Thread-1");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " interrpted");
            }
        };

        // run in a separate thread
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(task);
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(task);
        thread2.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        running0.set(false);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        running1.set(false);
    }
}
```

I would suggest that you give your threads explicit names upon creation.  Relying on the names that Java gives the threads may get you in trouble one day, as there is no guarantee that those names won't change in future versions of Java.  The docs only state: "If a name is not specified when a thread is created, a new name is generated for it".